# How to update multiple records at once with subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I've got a list of buildings to update, by pulling another field from another table I've got a list of their pk/fk identifiers. I'd love to do it all at once instead of throwing dozens of individual update statements, each with one id in it.

Seems like such a simple task I'm positive it has to be easy and I'm just not seeing how to do it right yet. SQL seems to abhor using 'where x in ()" on an update.

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Here's what I'm trying to run.

```
update accountinginfo
set companyname = (select facilityname from facility)
where facilityid in (12345,12346,12347)
```

What's the right way to 'loop', for lack of a better term, through records like this, without using a cursor?

[sample record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he0Cg.png)

Comment: share two tables sample data and what you want to update

Comment: I guess the real question is why are you storing the same data in two places. Keep one source of truth: if you need to find the `facilityname` then write a query or a view joining the two tables

Comment: @Charlieface The two fields can have different values. In this case, the request was "Just make the companyname match the facilityname in the other table for these" 

I'm only updating ~20 out of ~30,000 records. 

I tried joining it but it blows up when I add the table identifier, ie

update accountinginfo a -- I get 'Incorrect syntax near 'a'. Expecting SET. 

Doesn't matter where I put the join in the query or if I try to add the identifier further down. that just throws a 'multipart identifier could not be bound.' 

I'll look into a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery needs to tie in to the outer query.

```
update a
set companyname = (select facilityname f from facility WHERE f.facilityid = a.facilityid)
FROM accountinginfo a
where a.facilityid in (12345,12346,12347)
```

Comment: So the where clause is like an ad-hoc join? 

I tried that but SSMS blows up on the first line "Incorrect syntax near 'a'. Expecting SET"

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it up. EDIT: When you alias in an `UPDATE`, need to do that in the `FROM` clause. And yes, the `WHERE` is the join, when the sub-query is in the `SELECT` that is how you do it, when it is in the `FROM` you alias the whole thing and join 'normally'.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. I see where I had it busted now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a joined update:

```sql
update a
set companyname = f.facilityname
from accountinginfo a
join facility f on f.facilityid = a.facilityid
where f.facilityid in (12345, 12346, 12347);
```